# How can I delete all unreferenced files in an Xcode project?

Tags: xcode, reference, delete-file

I added a bunch of files at different times to my project then later deleted them, and I forgot to make Xcode trash the files in addition to the references. Since Xcode doesn't store the grouped files in separate directories, I now have hundreds of files and folders all together in my project directory, and it would be a pain to sift through and take out the ones I don't want.

I'm using Xcode 5. How do I make it automatically delete all files in my project directory that aren't actually part of the project? Note: I am not referring to files referenced in my source code, just the Xcode project itself.

I had the idea of using the built-in git functionality to solve this by pushing the project to Github, deleting the local copy, then cloning it back. But apparently, removing referenced files in Xcode won't prevent them from being committed. If there's some option to make Xcode only include referenced files in the git repository, that would work too (even though it's a hack workaround).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there are no trivial way to find unreferenced files in an Xcode project.

I wrote [a tool](https://github.com/Frizlab/find_unreferenced_xcode_files) to do it though.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get the utility in the accepted answer to install, so made my own quick and dirty solution. Run this from the root of your project, adjust `.swift` to match the extensions you're interested in:

```
#!/bin/zsh
PROJECT=YourProjectName
for file in $PROJECT*/**/*.swift
do
    grep -q "$(basename $file)" ../$PROJECT.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj || echo "$file"
done
```

This will print out any files whose name doesn't appear in project.pbxproj. It relies on the fact that project.pbxproj contains comments with the file names in them. It is not 100% reliable as **an unreferenced file with the same name as a different referenced file will not be reported** but it's better than nothing!

Comment: Nice, I'm guessing lots has changed since Xcode 5. Note to readers, you could replace `echo` with `rm` to delete them in one go.